# Symfony2 - Doctrine - form in loop

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, twig

I want create a list of comments from database. 
For each of them I want to add form with like/dislike option

Issue: I know how to create one form, but there I need to use twig to iterate collection of comments and there put a forms inside for each comment.

Any idea how to handle this problem?
Couldnt find anything about this in documentation. Maybe I am looking bad way.
Please for help

Answer (score 1):

The collection type should help you out:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: This could help me if I wouldnt have twig loop with other data. This way gives me prototype to use. But when I put prototype to twig loop in one place it wont work for other loops. It could start once for every loop. Insted of that I need new form like/dislike for every loop. I am not sure that I wrote it clear :/

Answer (score 0):

Just create buttons like and dislike on you blogpage and use AJAX that calls the likeAction in your controller. The route to this controller needs to have a variabele $id pointing to the comment that has to be liked or disliked. In this controller you retrieve the user that is logged in (if possible) and you store the like with the user_id and comment_id into the database if the same like isnt available yet.

```
<button data-id="{{comment.id}}" class="btn-like">Like</button>

$(function() {
  $(".btn-like").click(function() {
    var comment_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = "{{ path('app_comment_like', {'id': 'comment_id'}) }}";
    url = url.replace("comment_id", comment_id);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "post"
    });
  });
});
```